# Удаление элемента из массива

Tags: java

```
char k3[]=textField3.getText().toCharArray();
```

Подскажите плис, как удалить из массива элемент.

```
k3[i]=null;//пишет error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы уверены, что Вам нужно работать с массивом типа char? В любом случае вот код:

```
    public char[] remove(char[] symbols, int index)
    {           
         if (index >= 0 && index < symbols.length)
         {
             char[] copy = new char[symbols.length-1];
             System.arraycopy(symbols, 0, copy, 0, index);
             System.arraycopy(symbols, index+1, copy, index, symbols.length-index-1);
             return copy;
         }          
         return symbols;
    }
```

Comment: А for( ... ) тут зачем ?

Просто

if (index >= 0 && index < symbols.length) {
    ...
}

чем не устраивает ?

Второй раз уже это комментирую.

Comment: Конечно же, цикл тут не нужен. Просто переделал код, который удалял вхождение символа. Ночью плохо соображал.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
   remove(k3[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char[] removeItem(char[] array, int index){
    for (int i = index; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]